# loading NA values from r to sql

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to load a dataframe from r to sql and am having trouble getting the NAs to load to their equivalent NULL in sql.  They are coming up as blank cells instead.  Example data:

```
data.frame(name = c('Sara', 'Matt', 'Kyle', 'Steve', 'Maggie', NA, 'Alex', 'Morgan'),
student_id = c(123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130),
           score = c(78, 83, 91, NA, 88, 92, NA, 77))
```

Table schema: student_score with columns name (varchar), student_id (int),  and score (int)

R code:

```
load = "Insert into schema.student_score (name, student_id, score) values"  
data = list()  
for (i in seq(nrow(df))) {  
info = paste0("('", df$name[i], "','",  
df$student_id[i], "','",  
df$score[i], "')")  
data[[i]] = info  
}  
rows = do.call(rbind, data)  
values = paste(rows[,1], collapse = ',')  
send = paste0(load, values)  
dbSendQuery(conn, send)
```

and when they are loaded in sql it comes out

```
name    student_id    score
Sara    123           78
Matt    124           83
Kyle    125           91
Steve   126           
Maggie  127           88
        128           92
Alex    129           
Morgan  130           77
```

I want the blank values to be replaced by NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `NA` gets translated as `"NA"`. You need to replace all `'NA'` in `send` to `NULL`. Simply add below code at the end -

```
send <- gsub("'NA'", "NULL", send)
send

"Insert into schema.student_score (name, student_id, score) values('Sara','123','78'),('Matt','124','83'),('Kyle','125','91'),('Steve','126',NULL),('Maggie','127','88'),(NULL,'128','92'),('Alex','129',NULL),('Morgan','130','77')"
```

Comment: In this case the null gets sent as a character string instead of the null (blank equivelent)

Comment: @theofficefan12 Yeah, I thought so. Updated the answer. Thanks!